# unexpected results with GMT parsing in java

Tags: java, parsing, time

I am using the code below to parse a String into a date GMT->EDT.  I don't understand the results I am seeing.

```
        SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss");
        TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
        dformat.setTimeZone(gmt);
        Date d = dformat.parse(time);
```

If time = "20111019-13:00:00", then d ends up being Wed Oct 19 09:00:00 EDT 2011. However, if time = "20111019-12:59:59", d somehow ends up being Tue Oct 18 20:59:59 EDT 2011.  How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant `HH:mm:ss` for the time component, not `hh:mm:ss`. It was using the 12-hour clock, and interpreting 12:59:59 as effectively 00:59:59.

Note that your parsing does *not* perform a conversion to a particular time zone - because `Date` *doesn't know about time zones*. You're only seeing EDT because (I suspect) you're printing out `d.toString()`, which always uses the local time zone.

The Java date/time API is pretty awful - if you possibly can, I'd strongly advise you to move to [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, where you would use a `DateTime` which *does* have a time zone... and lets you convert between them.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the code where I actually convert when I noticed the problem was in the section that I posted.  Makes sense, thank you!  I also am not a fan of the date functionality but it is my only choice in this case.